# Downloading Files from a Crystal Report

Tags: sql, eclipse, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a crystal report I am trying to pull images, word docs, and zip files onto the report as a downloadable hyperlink so that whoever prints the report will have the ability to download the "attachment" they choose locally to their desktop.

[image]

The files are stored in folders on a database server. The view in the database named "vAttachmentsReport" contains the file path which points to the folders where the images, word docs, and zip files are stored. I have attempted to create a formula:

[image]

however, still no luck. I haven't found much information or any articles/examples of anyone else doing this. Has anyone else seen any examples or created something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about doing this in eclipse, but if you open it up in the Crystal Report Editor you can right click > Format Field and go to the Hyperlink tab. This tab gives you several options for linking other files, websites, ect. via Hyperlinks. Since your database field already has the location, I would recommend adding the name of the file from your database as a field in the report and in its Hyperlink tab select the 'A Website on the Internet' radio button. Then click the formula button and enter the name of the database field that contains your file path.

Note: this will only work if you can enter the file path into your Internet Browser's address bar and download the file. If that doesn't work you may need to add a prefix to the formula with the server's name or the website's name. To this up: you need the whole website address like "http://textfiles.com/100/914bbs.txt" as a result of your Hyperlink formula.

Comment: This is similar to how I am doing it now, but the link does not download. I might have a permissions issue where the file won't download for users without administrative access to that view.

Comment: Does the hyperlink contain the whole path address or just the server's local path address? Also, have you tried to use a path to download a file from the address bar in your Web Browser?